# Conditional hotkey or include in AutoHotKey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, remapping

Is there a way to define a Hotkey conditionally in AutoHotKey? I want to do different keyboard mappings for different machines with different physical keyboards.

This is what I want to do:

```
RegRead, ComputerName, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName, ComputerName
If ( ComputerName = BDWELLE-DIM8300 ) 
{
 #Include %A_ScriptDir%\Mappings-BDWELLE-DIM8300.ahk
}
```

OR

```
RegRead, ComputerName, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName, ComputerName
If ( ComputerName = BDWELLE-DIM8300 ) 
{
 LWin::LAlt
    [more hotkey definitions that only apply to this machine]
}
```

but since AHK parses Hotkey definitions and #Include statements BEFORE interpreting If statements, the Hotkeys definitions (whether buried in an #Include or not) do not respect the If condition.

Thanks for pointing me to AutoHotKey_L!

Do you have a specific example of how to conditionally define a hotkey? The syntax is very confusing. Here's what I'm trying (after having installed AutoHotKey_L.exe in place of AutoHotKey.exe):

```
RegRead, ComputerName, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName, ComputerName 
#If ( ComputerName = BDWELLE-DIM8300 ) 
LWin::LAlt
```

but that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, I know, but I just had to do this this morning, and this is how I got it working in AutoHotkey_L:

```
#If %computername% = work-computer
^h::MsgBox Work
#If

#If %computername% != work-computer
^h::MsgBox Not at Work
#If
```

The key point is that your computer name *is not quoted*. That tripped me up for quite a while.

Hope it helps somebody out!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Hotkey command](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) - it can create or modify HKs dynamically anywhere in a script.

Answer (score 1):

Lifehacker presented an AHK script called [AutoInclude](http://lifehacker.com/5457619/autohotkey-autoinclude-organizes-consolidates-your-ahk-workflow) that help you select which scripts to use on different computers. It accomplishes this by textually concatenating scripts into one file and then running that one file.

Disclaimer: I have not used it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating separate scripts for each PC containing the PC-specific hotkeys, including a common script for the shared hotkeys, and using a separate script to launch the appropriate script.

**Common.ahk**

```
; Common hotkeys go here
```

**[PC Name].ahk**

```
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\Common.ahk

; PC-specific hotkeys go here
```

**Load.ahk**

```
If FileExist(A_ScriptDir . "\" . A_ComputerName . ".ahk")
    Run "autohotkey.exe" %A_ScriptDir%\%A_ComputerName%.ahk
Else
    Run "autohotkey.exe" %A_ScriptDir%\Common.ahk
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [Autohotkey L](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic34070.html) a shot. Among other things, it has a #If statement, which works just like #IfWinActive, but for arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to AutoHotKey_L! Do you have a specific example of how to conditionally define a hotkey? The syntax is very confusing. Here's what I'm trying (after having installed AutoHotKey_L.exe in place of AutoHotKey.exe): 

    RegRead, ComputerName, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName, ComputerName
    #If ( ComputerName = BDWELLE-DIM8300 ) 
    LWin::LAlt

but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I think you have to end it with another #if, like #IfWinActive, but I've never actually *used* AHKL, sorry :(